# Duplicates message in pop3

Tags: java, sockets, pop3

When im doing my lab project ("pop3 mail client") im find something mystery in server answer- messages duplicates two times, for example:

```
S: Subject: Test 1
S: From: *** *** <***@gmail.com>
S: To: ***@mail.ru
S: Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=***
S: X-Spam: Not detected
S: X-Mras: Ok
S: X-Mru-Authenticated-Sender: ***@gmail.com
S: 
S: --04***********************49
S: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
S: 
S: Hello
S: 
S: --04***********************49
S: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
S: 
S: Hello
S: 
S: --047d7b10c7979b168d04d00bd749--
S: 
S: .
```

Is this normal?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Not particularly as far as I know, but we'd have to see your code to say more.

Comment: I suggest you search the web for that Content-Type value "multipart/alternative"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal.  Note the message's type: `multipart/alternative`.

The `multipart/alternative` MIME type contains multiple bodies, each of which is typically the message body in some other format.  In this case, the sender's mail client included both HTML and plain text versions of the message body.  The receiver would select the most appropriate format and display that version of the message.